# groovy regular expression not working as I'd hoped

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I'm trying to get the regular expression from valid to match and println Testing for each... the valid form of data should be `schedules[##]`    (`#` being a number)

```
    def valid = ~/^('schedules')('[')[0-9]{2}(']')$/

    params.entrySet().findAll {
        valid.matcher(it.key).matches()
    }.each {

        println("Testing")

    }
```

I've also tried  `~/^('schedules[')[0-9]{2}(']')$/`

anyone see what I'm doing wrong? cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def params = [ 'schedules[32]'  : 'pass 1',
               'schedules[tim]' : 'fail 2',
               'schedules[4]'   : 'fail 3',
               'schedules[09]'  : 'pass 4',
               'invalid'        : 'fail 5' ]

params.entrySet().findAll {
    // Look for start of line then 'schedules[' then 2 chars 0-9, then ] and EOL
    it.key ==~ /^schedules\[([0-9]{2})]$/
}.each {
    println it.value
}
```

Because we have grouped the `[0-9]{2}` bit, we can get a bit more complex:

```
params.entrySet().findResults { entry ->
    ( entry.key =~ /^schedules\[([0-9]{2})]$/ ).with {
        matches() ? [ key:entry.key, value:entry.value, num:it[0][1] ] : null
    }
}.each {
    println "param $it.key with number $it.num = $it.value"
}
```

Which prints:

```
param schedules[32] with number 32 = pass 1
param schedules[09] with number 09 = pass 4
```